# What is a "normal value", and why do I need it to slice a pie?

Tags: geometry, functions

I am working on a Pie Chart, and am using a tutorial that states…

> An easy way to get the relative value is to normalize the array and use the normal value `[0, 1]` to arrive at the angle of the slice, ie. `normal * 2 * M_PI`. For example, if the normal value is `0.5`, the angle of the slice will be `M_PI` or `180°`.

What do they mean, by *normal*? Ok, so I looked it up (hey, I got a 5 on the Calculus AP, but that was a *long time ago*).. and realize now that to *normalize* means to

> multiply (a series, function, or item of data) by a factor that makes the norm or some associated quantity such as an integral equal to a desired value (usually 1).
>   • Computing (in floating-point representation) express (a number) in the standard form with regard to the position of the radix point, usually immediately following the first nonzero digit.

OK, so I'm sure I could figure that out.. but again, imagine this is a golden-retriever trying to do this... Going into it, I had *imagined* I'd be calculating my "slices" like…

```
10 items = 100%
( item.count / items.total ) * 360 = slice.angle
```

Seems simple enough.  Maybe too simple.  Am I missing something here?  Is there a reason that I should be using normalization for this, opposed to something more familiar / simplistic?  Thanks.

Comment: You want the angle to be `(item.count/items.total)*360`. E.g., with $2$ of $10$ items you want $0.2\cdot 360=72$ degrees, not $0.2/360$ degrees!

Comment: Corrected.  My golden retriever is an idiot.

Comment: When you make that revised calculation, you’re essentially doing what the tutorial suggests: `item.count/items.total` is the normalized value of `item.count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you calculate the appropriate angle for the segment representing items of Type A, say, as $$\frac{\text{number of items of Type A}}{\text{total number of items}}\cdot 360°\;,$$ you’re doing exactly what the tutorial suggests, because $$\frac{\text{number of items of Type A}}{\text{total number of items}}\tag{1}$$ **is** the normalized value of $$\text{number of items of Type A}\;.$$ If you have no items of Type A, the fraction $(1)$ is $0$; if every item is of Type A, it’s $1$; if half of the items are of Type A, it’s $0.5$; and so on.